# Best practice to save cookies #JAVA

Tags: java, cookies

i want to know how to save data in cookies in order to prevent user from having to login every time he visits the website

so what type of data should i stock and how to verify them when the user visits my website again

Comment: This is way too broad of a question, this encompasses session management, secure logins, cookies and more. This is not something someone can type an answer out with a few hundred characters

Comment: Usually you'd store a bearer token of some sort on the client side. You have the client authenticate by calling one of your endpoints with a username/password.. you send them a token in return.. then they use that token with future requests. If you wanna save that in a cookie on the front end, that's fine so long as you don't make them expire. Without more details that's about as good an answer as you can get.